# When launching multiple instances, is there a way to assign each EC2 instance a pre-known unique ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If one launches 5 EC2 instances in a single go, is there a way to uniquely ID each instance with a pre-known ID (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) in the User data setting of **Step 3: Configure Instance Details**?

e.g. User data:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
   #assign a unique number 1 through 5 to this instance
   echo $id > $dir
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a field called `ami-launch-index` that varies for each instance that is launched, starting with zero.

You can obtain it with:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index
```

For details, see: [AMI launch index value - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMI-launch-index-examples.html)

Comment: It's not very clear in the documentation, but I believe the ami-launch-index doesn't work for Auto Scaling Groups (each index is 0)

Comment: That is correct. The field is only used when multiple instances are launched in the same `RunInstances()` call. When Auto Scaling launches an instance, it launches them individually since each is typically in a different Availability Zone, or launched later in response to a scaling event.